# Pixi.js - How to instantiate dynamic objects from library

Tags: canvas, pixi.js, animate-cc

Using Pixi.js 7.3.1 in combination with @pixi/animate 3

Reading "Only things added to the stage will be exported!" from npm @pixi/animate documentation, is it even possible to dynamically instantiate a named object (movie clip) from the library. Same as we can perform with Create.js :

window = new lib.Window50()

Otherwise, what is the best technique to deal with "on demand" elements only ? Playing with Display Object renderable state ?

Thanks for support